# Unknown Edge error code #c004e005

Tags: microsoft-edge, ortc

I’m trying to build oRTC application with latest Edge version. Followin code:

```
 iceGatherer.getLocalCandidates().forEach(iceGatherer.onlocalcandidate);
```

throws error “c004e005” that don’t have any description. Anyone familiar with oRTC in Edge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The “c004e005” error code is for an invalid state. You can find a list of the Microsoft Edge ORTC error codes in the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt723462(v=vs.85).aspx).

> The invalid state is likely thrown on the RTCIceServer regarding the IceGatherer, IceTransport, or DtlsTransport in the TURN server configuration.