# Could not complete the operation due to error c004e005

Tags: javascript, webrtc, microsoft-edge

I have a delay function as below:

```
 var delayToggle = (function () {
        var timer = 0;
        return function (callback, ms) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
        };
    })();
```

I call this when I click on video/audio toggle button. Invoking it as follows:

```
delayToggle(toggleMyVideo, 500);
```

On Edge it gives this error:

> Could not complete the operation due to error c004e005.

I am not sure what the error is and how to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: If you do a simple call like `delayToggle(function(){}, 500);`, does it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unknown Edge error code #c004e005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35986558/unknown-edge-error-code-c004e005)

Comment: @Adriani6 OP also asks why this is happening and the answer to that can't be found there

Comment: @nickzoum  Yes it works. hm, could this error be related to this warning I am getting: Timeout for addRemoteCandidate. Consider sending an end-of-candidates notification ?

Comment: My guess it has something to do with toggleMyVideo and not the code above.

Comment: @epascarello it works fine on Chrome though.

Comment: so.............

Comment: I thought there is no issue with that function. However if am toggling on Edge  I am closing all webRTC connections for this participant, then restarting  the process as if the participant just joined. It's code written by someone else, I am not sure why it is this way.

Comment: @A.Blanc So does calling `toggleMyVideo` without a timeout throw an error?

Comment: @nickzoum no it isn't throwing an error, only the warning about end of candidates.

Comment: @nickzoum If i am toggling without waiting at least 5 seconds between each toggle I am getting the same error actually.

Comment: @A.Blanc Seems like the problem is in `toggleMyVideo`

Comment: Could  you please provide the toggleMyVideo function? From the limited code I could not reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was going on. When I toggled the video on Edge I restarted the whole peer connection establishment with the existing audio stream (and new video stream depending on whether video was toggled on or off), so when I tried to add audio to my audio element, there already was the existing one with the same id which threw the error. Added a check there, the error isn't showing.